# ¿En vb.net como filtrar un dataview?

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, windows-forms, string, poo

Tengo un dataview que alimenta un datagridview, y un combobox que filtra la tabla con base en el nombre, pero quisiera poder aplicar el filtro sin limitarse a un solo campo. Actualmente está así:

```
dv.RowFilter = String.Format("NOMBRE like '%{0}%'", t_buscar.Text)
```

Pero solo puedo filtrar por nombre, si quisiera que buscara también en el campo Estado por ejemplo ¿cómo puedo extender el filtro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un poco tarde para la respuesta pero puede servir para alguien que tenga el mismo problema, supongamos que el dataview tiene tres campos NOMBRE, APELLIDO, CIUDAD, y tenemos un textBox con el nombre txBuscar que es donde se escribiria lo que se desea buscar. Se podría hacer el siguiente filtro.

`dv.RowFilter ="NOMBRE like '%" & txBuscar.Text & "%' OR APELLIDO like '%" & txBuscar.Text & "%' OR CIUDAD like '%" & txBuscar.Text & "%'"`

Se podría colocar en el evento Click de un botón buscar o en el evento KeyUp del cuadro de texto.

Answer (score 0):

En el combobox esta la propiedad SelectedItem donde puedes validar el valor seleccionado en éste, una vez que tengas este valor puedes validar para que te muestre el valor solicitado, te adjunto un ejemplo:

```
Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Case "NOMBRE"
            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("NOMBRE like '%{0}%'", t_buscar.Text)
        Case "APELLIDO"
            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("APELLIDO like '%{0}%'", t_buscar.Text)
        Case "ESTADO"
            dv.RowFilter = String.Format("ESTADO like '%{0}%'", t_buscar.Text)
End Select
```

Comment: Entiendo que entonces es imposible. Solo se puede emplear una sola columna a la vez. Me imaginaba como en SQL que puedes poner algo como Where nombre like '%Nombre%' or Estado like '%Estado%' y que busca coincidencias en ambas columnas a la vez.